# What's the difference between CGI.unescape and URI.decode_www_form_component?

Tags: ruby, encoding

These functions seem to do the same thing.

```
irb> CGI.unescape "Sloths%3A+Society+and+Habitat"
=> "Sloths: Society and Habitat"

irb> URI.decode_www_form_component "Sloths%3A+Society+and+Habitat"
=> "Sloths: Society and Habitat"
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These methods are *very* similar. They both accept a string and an encoding and return a string in the specified encoding with the `%` escapes decoded. But there are differences:

### Invalid escapes

`URI.decode_www_form_component` raises an `ArgumentError` if the string contains invalid escape sequences.

```
URI.decode_www_form_component('%xz')
# ArgumentError: invalid %-encoding (%xz)
```

`CGI.unescape` simply ignores them.

```
CGI.unescape('%xz')
# "%xz"
```

### Invalid encodings

`CGI.unescape` ignores your specified encoding if the result is invalid

```
p CGI.unescape("\u263a", 'ASCII')
# "☺"
```

`URI.decode_www_form_component` doesn't care

```
p URI.decode_www_form_component("\u263a", 'ASCII')
# "\xE2\x98\xBA"
```

---

Lastly (and I hesitate to even mention this), `URI.decode_www_form_component` is *slightly* faster because it uses a precomputed Hash to decode all 485 valid escape codes (it's case-sensitive), whereas `CGI.unescape` actually interprets the hex code and repacks it as a character.