# I need to convert 'jonathan-morón-16394669' into 'jonathan-mor%C3%B3n-16394669'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, replace, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to solve an issue because sometimes data like 'jonathan-mor%C3%B3n-16394669' gets saved and sometimes data like 'jonathan-morón-16394669' gets saved. So I need a smooth way to move around between those two versions of the string to be able to compare things and realize it's the same via matching them and just carry on without saving something twice in the DB.

I know I could just start using something like this but in reverse:

```
line = line.replace("%C3%A9","e")
line = line.replace("%C3%B3","o")
line = line.replace("%E2%80%93","-")
line = line.replace("%C3%A6","e")
line = line.replace("%C3%A8","e")
line = line.replace("%C3%A0","e")
line = line.replace("%C3%A1","i")
line = line.replace("%C5%82","l")
line = line.replace("%C5%84","n")
line = line.replace("%C3%BF", "y")
line = line.replace("%C3%BE", "p")
line = line.replace("%C3%BD", "y")
line = line.replace("%C3%BC", "u")
line = line.replace("%C3%BB", "u")
line = line.replace("%C3%BA", "u")
line = line.replace("%C3%B9", "o")
line = line.replace("%C3%B6", "o")
line = line.replace("%C3%B5", "o")
line = line.replace("%C3%B4", "o")
line = line.replace("%C3%B3", "o")
line = line.replace("%C3%B2", "o")
line = line.replace("%C3%B1", "n")
line = line.replace("%C3%B0", "e")
line = line.replace("%C3%AC", "i")
line = line.replace("%C3%AD", "i")
line = line.replace("%C3%AE", "i")
line = line.replace("%C3%AF", "i")
line = line.replace("%C3%81","A")
line = line.replace("%C3%82","A")
line = line.replace("%C3%83","A")
line = line.replace("%C3%84","A")
line = line.replace("%C3%85","A")
line = line.replace("%C3%86","AE")
line = line.replace("%C3%87","C")
line = line.replace("%C3%88","E")
line = line.replace("%C3%89","E")
line = line.replace("%C3%8A","E")
line = line.replace("%C3%8B","E")
line = line.replace("%C3%8C","I")
line = line.replace("%C3%8D","I")
line = line.replace("%C3%8E","I")
line = line.replace("%C3%8F","I")
line = line.replace("%C3%90","D")
line = line.replace("%C3%91","N")
line = line.replace("%C3%92","O")
line = line.replace("%C3%93","O")
line = line.replace("%C3%94","O")
line = line.replace("%C3%95","O")
line = line.replace("%C3%96","O")
line = line.replace("%C3%98","O")
line = line.replace("%C3%99","U")
line = line.replace("%C3%9A","U")
line = line.replace("%C3%9B","U")
line = line.replace("%C3%9C","U")
line = line.replace("%C3%9D","Y")
line = line.replace("%C3%9F","B")
line = line.replace("%C3%a0","a")
line = line.replace("%C3%a1","a")
line = line.replace("%C3%a2","a")
line = line.replace("%C3%a3","a")
...
```

But I need a more Rails way solution, elegant, simple

Comment: Like this `URI.decode('jonathan-mor%C3%B3n-16394669')`?

Comment: I'm looking for something the other way around, something like Something.method('jonathan-morón-16394669') and get 'jonathan-mor%C3%B3n-16394669'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CGI::escape](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI/Util.html#method-i-escape)

```
CGI::escape('jonathan-morón-16394669') # => jonathan-mor%C3%B3n-16394669
```

You could go also the other way around with [CGI::unescape](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI/Util.html#method-i-unescape)

```
CGI::unescape('jonathan-mor%C3%B3n-16394669') # => jonathan-morón-16394669
```

Comment: So both work, thanks! Which es better or which would you suggest I use CGI::escape or URI.encode?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783879/whats-the-difference-between-cgi-unescape-and-uri-decode-www-form-component.

Comment: Looks like CGI::escape could be a better fit, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to razvans! The answer I needed was

```
URI.encode("jonathan-morón-16394669")
```

which outputs

```
[19] pry(main)> URI.encode("jonathan-morón-16394669")
=> "jonathan-mor%C3%B3n-16394669"
```